# Jquery remote validation shows 1 as error message

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

This is my client side validation script :

```
 jQuery('#myForm_members').validate({
        rules:{
            user_userpassword2:{equalTo:'#user_userpassword'},
            user_username: {required: true,remote: 
                               {url:'option/members/member.php?task=check_user_name',type:'post',async: false}}            
        },
        messages:{
            user_userpassword2:{equalTo:'Password mismatched.'},
            user_username:{remote:'User name exists.'}            
        }
        });
```

Server side script:

```
    $num_rows=$this->count_rows($sql);
    if($num_rows>0)
        echo 0;
    else
        echo 1;
```

When this validation returns false, it works fine
[image: Working on false condition]

But when this validation returns true, it doesn't work and returns 1 as error
[image: Returing 1 as error]

Comment: Have you tried removing the "echo 1" case from the php script? Chances are jQuery's validate() displays just what it received from the server-side script when answer is non-zero.

Comment: yeah instead echoing 1, I printed json_encode(true) like what @Max explained below and that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
if($r>0)
    echo json_encode( false );
else
    echo json_encode( true );
```